# Can I, and How to configure the branch naming patern for branch binded to issues in Gitlab-CE?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-8, gitlab-ce

In Gitlab, there were a naming convention for new features branches created FROM and FOR an issue : `my-awesome-issue-title-<ISSUE_ID>`

If we folow this convention, Gitlab bind automatically the branch with the issue, and even the merge requests created from this branch.

This is a very awesome feature because we can name all of our branches with a custom naming convention, with prefixes, and finishing with the ID of the issue make the trick.

For example we can create these branches :

- `features/add-awesome-button-354`
- `features/improve-cool-action-398`
- `hotfixess/fix-https-performance-issue-512`

and so on... and Gitlab automagically bind our branches to  their matching issues. Great!

But from the last GitLab upgrade (Community Edition 8.9.2), the naming convention seems to changed  for  `<ISSUE_ID>-my-awesome-issue-title`

This is very painful now to bind the issues to the branches, or we have to give up our loved custom prefixed naming convention...  :-(

Is it possible to configure that patern to get back with the previous one or my own ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but it is not possible to configure this kind of behaviour. You would need to make those changes yourself in the code and rebuild GitLab (which is tedious and will break on update).

[This](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/3708/commits) Merge Request has changed this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the link to the right commits !